# How to display custom type post article on main post (single.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display my **faq post (custom type post)** on **main post (single.php)**. I am using category to match the posts. If any category from **faq post (custom type post)** matches category of **main post (single.php)** then display FAQ post content below main post. Category need not match all but atleast one.

```
<?php while (have_posts()):
    the_post(); ?>

<h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

  <?php get_template_part("widgets/cta"); ?>
        <?php
        $cat = the_category();
        echo $cat[0]->cat_name;
        ?>
        
        <?php
        $args_faq = ["post_type" => "faq", "posts_per_page" => 2];
        $faq_loop = new WP_Query($args_faq);
        while ($faq_loop->have_posts()):
            $faq_loop->the_post();

            $category_faq = the_category();
            $cat_slug_faq = $category_faq[0]->cat_name;
            echo $cat_slug_faq[0]->cat_name;

            if ($cat_slug_faq == $cat_slug) {
                echo "<h4>" . get_the_title() . "</h4>";

                echo the_content();
            }
        endwhile;
        ?> 


      <?php
endwhile; ?>
```

**FAQ CUSTOM POST TYPE**

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_faqs' );

function create_faqs() {
    register_post_type( 'faqs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'FAQs',
                'singular_name' => 'FAQ',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Faq',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Faq',
                'new_item' => 'New Faq',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Faq',
                'search_items' => 'Search FAQs',
                'not_found' => 'No FAQs found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No faqs found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Faq'
            ),
            
 
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            // 'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-help',
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-help',
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
function reg_cat() {
         register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','faqs');
    }
add_action('init', 'reg_cat');
```

Comment: For clarity: does your main post have one category? Or multiple? If your main post has multiple, what category term would you want to match with your faq posts?

Comment: @disinfor My main post has multiple categories and also faq posts has multiple categories. Therefore, I need the statement to do search of any term that is the same and that is available between both posts even if it one category. I have tried using this `if (count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) === 0) {
  // No values from array1 are in array 2
} else {
  // There is at least one value from array1 present in array2
}` but it is not working also

Comment: Do your main posts (I'm assuming the default Post type) and faq post type share the default category taxonomy? Or does FAQs have a registered taxonomy that's different? This will help.

Comment: @disinfor it does not share the default category taxonomy

Comment: Based on the code you shared, it does. You are assigning the default category as a registered taxonomy for your FAQs. Just need to make sure this is accurate or our answers will not help.

Comment: @disinfor its not working even after making sure both share the default category taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.

1. `the_category()` doesn't return anything, it echoes the terms links.
2. `the_content()` also echoes so you should not add `echo` before this function.
3. `the_content()` shouldn't be wrapped in `<p></p>` tag.
4. You're not using `wp_reset_postdata()` in your custom query.
5. Your logic is not good for your requirements.
6. Necessary validations are missing in your code.

There is a simplified code for requirements.

**Note: I have not tested the code, so there could be typos and mistakes which can create errors so make sure you have FTP access to modify the files to fix the error, If you're using the WordPress file editor then test the code in localhost or somewhere else then upload in live websites**

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    ?>

    <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

    <?php get_template_part( 'widgets/cta' ); ?>

    <?php vh_display_post_faqs( get_the_ID() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The above code is your `single.php` template file, I have added `vh_display_post_faqs()` which takes the post id and outputs the faqs content after doing the validations.

The below code will go to `functions.php`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Display faq lists from matching post categories.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 */
function vh_display_post_faqs( $post_id = 0 ) {
    // Return if post id is empty.
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the categories' ids using the passed post id.
    $categories_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    // Validate for empty ids or wp errors.
    if ( empty( $categories_ids ) || is_wp_error( $categories_ids ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Prepare query args, using tax query.
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'faqs',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'tax_query'      => array( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.SlowDBQuery
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $categories_ids,
        ),
    );

    // Run query and fetch faq posts.
    $faqs = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // Check if we have posts from the query.
    if ( $faqs->have_posts() ) :

        // Loop through the query posts.
        while ( $faqs->have_posts() ) :
            $faqs->the_post();

            // Print the content.
            ?>
            <div class="faq-post">
                <h2 class="faq-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                <div class="faq-content"><?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php

        endwhile;

        // Reset the post data.
        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, your code is working but its not solving my issue. I need the script to compare categories of both main post and custom type post (faq post) and if atleast one category is matching then display custom type post content (faq post)

Comment: if the default `category` taxonomy is attached to both post types, the code will work fine. if you have custom taxonomy which you name "category" for faq post type only, then you'll have to modify the code and logic as per your setup, I can't solve that problem without knowing your complete setup in detail.

Comment: I have added FAQ CUSTOM POST TYPE to my main question above

Comment: I am unsure if you understood my last comment or not, if both post types(main and faq) don't share the same taxonomy then you'll have to change your logic since you're not clarifying the taxonomy connections between both posts, I can't help further. thanks.

Comment: The problem was the wrong post type value, in your initial question, you've used `faq` but your custom post type name is `faqs`

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: Even after making sure both share the default category taxonomy

Comment: Did you change `post_type'      => 'faqs' ? if yes then do some troubleshooting and debugging and check which part if working and what kind of results you're getting for each type of functions.

Comment: Yes, I changed `post_type' => 'faqs'

Comment: I am getting results of all categories which does not match atleast one category